# WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported]

Tags: java, json, spring, postman

[image][image][image]Hi Guys Please advice me on how to resolve this issue
I am trying to consume a rest web service
see the code below

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.cwg.entrust.entities.InputString;
import com.cwg.entrust.entities.TokenObject;
import com.cwg.entrust.services.MyConnectionProvider;
import com.cwg.entrust.services.TolenDAO;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;[![enter image description here][3]][3]
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TfaServiceController implements TolenDAO {
    java.sql.Connection con = null;
    java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Date date = new Date();
    String the_date = date.toString();
@PostMapping(value = { "/validateToken" }, 
            consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }
    , produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public Boolean getIsValidToken(@RequestBody Map<String, String> json_Input) throws Exception {
        String str = json_Input.get("str1") ;
        String token = json_Input.get("str2") ;

        Boolean result = false;

        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(token)) {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

see the payload below

```
{
    "str1": "test one",
    "str2": "two test"
}
```

Both Content-Type and Accept on Postman are set to `application/json`

But we keep getting below error

> WARNING: Resolved
>   [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
>   type 'application/json' not supported]

Kindly advice me on how to consume this webservice without issues
Thanks all.

Comment: `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` use this on your controller  and remove `@ResponseBody` from controller. Use `Response` as the return type from your controller. It will help you to further customize your controller. If possible make pojo for your RequestBody

Comment: how do I use response as the return type?

Comment: `public  ResponseEntity<?> confirmReset(@RequestBody Object object)` If using spring boot you can use something like this.            `return new ResponseEntity<>("return object here",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `@RestController` annotation at the class level , you do not have to use the `@ResponseBody` annotation at the method level to indicate that it is a Rest endpoint and that the response type of the controller method will be a `json`(by default for Rest in springboot) .Change your controller method to :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validateToken", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Boolean getIsValidToken(@RequestBody Map<String, String> json_Input) throws Exception {
    String str = json_Input.get("str1") ;
    String token = json_Input.get("str2") ;

    Boolean result = false;

    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(token)) {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Also instead of the  `@RequestMapping(value = "/validateToken", method = RequestMethod.POST)` you could use the `@PostMapping("/validateToken")` annotation if your springboot version supports it .In addition to that you could specify the type of data that the endpoint expects or produces using like :

```
@PostMapping(value = { "/validateToken" }, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
public Boolean getIsValidToken(@RequestBody Map<String, String> json_Input) throws Exception {
    String str = json_Input.get("str1") ;
    String token = json_Input.get("str2") ;

    Boolean result = false;

    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(token)) {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note : The consumes/produces can also be used with `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: it did not work. I updated the question and added the code edits you suggested

Comment: What is the request that you are sending, also what is the error that you reviece now. Please share entire stacktrace.

Comment: Request is "{
    "str1": "test one",
    "str2": "two test"
}"

Comment: error is Jun 08, 2020 7:43:55 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver logException
WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported]

Comment: <h1>HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type</h1>
 <hr class="line" />
 <p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p>
 <p><b>Description</b> The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not
  supported by this method on the target resource.</p>

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the request appropriately ? The `Content-type` of the request has to be `application/json` and the request body should be a json and not a string for this endpoint to properly receive the request.

Comment: How do You advise i send the request?

Comment: How are you making the request right now ? Please share the code or if from postman please share the screenshot of it so that we may advise. @MIikeEps

Comment: Check your headers in postman. In header tab. see content/type or You can see from the body tab. The last dropdown should be JSON

Comment: I've just copy&pasted your code. It works fine (except that I had to use `APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` instead of `APPLICATION_JSON`. If I disable the `contentType` in postman I get the same error as you do.

Comment: @jBuchholz yeah ! I also think MikeEps is missing the content type in header or setting the request body as a string or something.

Comment: @MIikeEps Instead of using `APPLICATION_JSON`  please use the one I provided in my anser as the MediaType. It will fix your issue.

Comment: @All, I updated the code to use APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE i also edited the question to show latest code, still geting error below. I also added screenshot of appl type in header tab of postman

Comment: Jun 08, 2020 8:12:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver logException
WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported]

Comment: Can you try removing the produces and consumes attributes from the controller method.And why are you implementing `TolenDAO ` at the controller layer.?

Comment: @ Ananthapadmanabhan, I removed the implementation and removed the produces and consumes attributes from the controller method, but it still did not work

Comment: @MIikeEps I just noticed that in your postman you are hitting `project/test/valdiateToken`. Is `project` your context path ? Otherwise please add it to the request mapping at class level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215556/discussion-between-miike-eps-and-ananthapadmanabhan).

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me too. It worked when I introduced the type String before the property name (json_Input in your case) and don't when I tried with my custom type.

At the end it was that I was referencing with the types of the properties instead of String type(as I am using mongodb).

So, Instead of

```
@DBRef
private CustomType customProperty
```

use:

```
@DBRef
private String customProperty
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Format the code